# Unable to save data with custom create serializer django rest_framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `note` on serializer `ProcessStepSerializer2`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `ProcessStep` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'ProcessStep' object has no attribute 'note'.**

My code : 
model file

```
class ProcessStep(BaseModel):
    process = models.ForeignKey('Process', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    priority = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    notes = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True), default=list)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    status = models.CharField(max_length=128,
                              null=True,
                              choices=(('inprogress', 'In Progress'), ('delayed',
                                                               'Delayed'), ('completed', 'Completed')) )
```

in views

```
note = request.data['note']
status = request.data['status']
process = ProcessStep.objects.get(id=slugid)
serializer = ProcessStepSerializer2(process, data=request.data, context={'request': request}, partial=True )
```

// serializer file

```
class NoteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    status=serializers.CharField()
    type=serializers.CharField()
    text=serializers.CharField()

class ProcessStepSerializer2(serializers.Serializer):
    note= NoteSerializer()
    status=serializers.CharField(required=True)
    user=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user = None
        request = self.context.get("request")
        if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
            user = request.user

        current_time = datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
        note = validated_data['note']
        note['time'] = current_time.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000
        note['user'] = UserSerializer(request.user).data
        validated_data['jsondumpednote'] = json.dumps(note)

        instance.notes.append(validated_data.get('jsondumpednote', instance.notes ))
        instance.status = validated_data.get('status', instance.status) 
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

So, it is returning the above error.

My doubts: 
1. when calling save on serializer in views, if am not passing previous instance than it should create, right?
2. similarly when updating, when object instance is passed, than it should update, right?
3. Does save method has anything else to do other than this?

Comment: Was my answer able to solve your issue? If not, I can amend it if you provide more information about the errors

Comment: i resolved the error. if you look at the seriaizer, this was not the typo but i was appending the note to list of notes. Actual error being i was updating the ProcessStep instance but processStep instance didn't contain the note field, so that was the err.

Answer (score 1):

Your serializer uses `note`, while your model uses `notes` (with an `s`). Change one or the other accordingly